# arp doesn't run in script when run through crontab

Tags: shell-script, scripting, cron, arp

I have a specific script that gets the `IP` address of a particular `MAC`. For this it uses `arp`, and it works correctly. The problem comes when I Program a `crontab` to run that script; it works fine and runs but the line where it runs the `arp` command does not work and, therefore the script does not finish correctly only if it's run from `crontab`.

The script is:

```
#!/bin/bash

subred=192.168.1.0/24
mac=aa:bb:cc:dd:ff:gg

log() {...}

log info "Init program"
ip=$(nmap -sP $subred >/dev/null && arp -an | grep $mac | awk '{print $2}' | sed 's/[()]//g')

if [  $ip  ]; then
    log ok "IP found in $ip"
else
    log error "IP not found"
fi

log info "Finished program"
```

This script has been configured to run on `crontab` every hour with `@hourly /root/machaunter.sh`. Time scheduling in `cron` is well done and the script runs smoothly, ruling out permission or script issues. The proof of them is the log file it generates:

```
29/04/2020 14:00:01 Init program
29/04/2020 14:00:06 IP not found
29/04/2020 14:45:59 Init program
29/04/2020 14:46:08 IP found in 192.168.1.173
29/04/2020 14:46:09 Finished program
29/04/2020 15:00:01 Init program
29/04/2020 15:00:10 IP not found
29/04/2020 16:00:01 Init program
29/04/2020 16:00:13 IP not found
29/04/2020 17:00:01 Init program
29/04/2020 17:00:07 IP not found
29/04/2020 18:00:01 Init program
29/04/2020 18:00:05 IP not found
29/04/2020 18:25:43 Init program
29/04/2020 18:25:50 IP found in 192.168.1.173
29/04/2020 18:25:51 Finished program
```

As you can see by the hours, the two times I ran the script manually worked correctly, but the rest of the Times didn't.

I've been debugging and added to the script tests until I find that, in the `arp` call does not show anything, however it does when I launch it manually (to do the tests I added the `log error "arp: $(arp -an)"` log and changed the crontab to run every minute `* * * * /root/machaunter.sh`)

```
30/04/2020 09:22:01 Init program
30/04/2020 09:22:01 arp:
30/04/2020 09:23:01 Init program
30/04/2020 09:23:01 arp:
30/04/2020 09:24:02 Init program
30/04/2020 09:24:02 arp:
30/04/2020 09:24:29 Init program
30/04/2020 09:24:29 arp: Address HWtype HWaddress Flags Mask Iface 192.168.1.46 ether 7e:2d:d1:ca:d9:c0 C br0 192.168.1.68 ether c894:66:dd:1c:c2:9d C br0 192.168.1.173 ether 48:48:59:e5:b8:5e C br0 192.168.1.1 ether bf:f1:54:4d:e3:25 C br0
30/04/2020 09:25:01 Init program
30/04/2020 09:25:01 arp:
30/04/2020 09:26:01 Init program
30/04/2020 09:26:01 arp:
30/04/2020 09:27:01 Init program
30/04/2020 09:27:01 arp:
30/04/2020 09:28:01 Init program
30/04/2020 09:28:01 arp:
30/04/2020 09:29:02 Init program
30/04/2020 09:29:02 arp:
30/04/2020 09:30:01 Init program
30/04/2020 09:30:01 arp:
30/04/2020 09:31:01 Init program
30/04/2020 09:31:01 arp:
```

As can be seen from the log, the `arp` command never returns data except for the only time I have manually launched it. Also, as you can see when calling this command doesn't terminate the script (we do not have the `Finished program` log)

Why is this happening? what solution would there be?

**UPDATE WITH CRON DAEMON LOG**

```
● cron.service - Regular background program processing daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/cron.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2020-04-27 18:09:19 UTC; 2 days ago
     Docs: man:cron(8)
 Main PID: 486 (cron)
   CGroup: /system.slice/cron.service
           └─486 /usr/sbin/cron -f

Apr 30 10:40:01 NanoPi-R1 CRON[14428]: (root) CMD (/root/machaunter.sh)
Apr 30 10:40:01 NanoPi-R1 CRON[14429]: (root) CMD (   /bin/bash /usr/bin/sync_ntp_rtc.sh /dev/rtc0)
Apr 30 10:40:01 NanoPi-R1 CRON[14421]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Apr 30 10:40:01 NanoPi-R1 CRON[14421]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Apr 30 10:40:04 NanoPi-R1 CRON[14420]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Apr 30 10:40:04 NanoPi-R1 CRON[14420]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Apr 30 10:41:01 NanoPi-R1 CRON[14459]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Apr 30 10:41:01 NanoPi-R1 CRON[14463]: (root) CMD (/root/machaunter.sh)
Apr 30 10:41:01 NanoPi-R1 CRON[14459]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Apr 30 10:41:01 NanoPi-R1 CRON[14459]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
```

**UPDATE WITH STDOUT OF COMMANDS**
I've added the XXXX redirect to the crontab command `>/tmp/logfile 2>&1`, lagging:

```
* * * * * /root/machaunter.sh >/tmp/logfile 2>&1
```

In `/tmp/logfile` I get:

```
30/04/2020 13:52:01 [info] Init program
/root/machaunter.sh: line 37: arp: command not found
30/04/2020 13:52:01 [info] arp:
```

Comment: Does the crontab environment have a `$PATH` value that includes the location of e.g. `nmap` (and the other tools you're using)? Are you getting errors emailed to you by the cron daemon, or in the cron log file?

Comment: It is always (to a first approximation) the environment. crontab does not read your profile. PATH is likely only "/bin:/usr/bin" (may include /sbin for root).

Comment: My `$PATH` variable and `/etc/environment` is `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games`. `nmap` works (it's in `/usr/bin`) but `arp` doesn't work (it's in `/usr/sbin`). How can I see which `PATH` variables have `cron`?

Comment: I updated the post with `systemctl` log information @Kusalananda.

Comment: @balon Ok, so the script definitively produces output that the cron daemon can't send to you because your machine does not have a mail transfer agent (MTA). You should redirect all output to a log file an inspect it. Do that by adding `>/tmp/logfile 2>&1` at the end of the command in the crontab. I'm expecting that file to contain "command not found" messages or similar when the job has run.

Comment: In your Cron entry add a redirect of stdout and stderr to a file you can access. I think your script is generating output, hence the lines no MTA installed, discarding output. This might help your analysis.

Comment: yes, I receive in the file `/tmp/logfile` the output `/root/machaunter.sh: line 37: arp: command not found` @Kusalananda. Only fails with `arp`, the rest of the commands work fine, could it be because `arp` is in `/usr/sbin`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The environment that cron is running your script in has a different value for the `PATH` variable compared to your ordinary interactive environment.

This means that your script does not know where the `arp` command is to be found, for example ([as mentioned in comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/583516/arp-doesnt-run-in-script-when-run-through-crontab?noredirect=1#comment1086646_583516)).

I would suggest that you make a note in what directories the tools that you use in your script by running `command -v` for each of them in an interactive shell, e.g.

```
command -v nmap
command -v arp
```

etc.

This will give you a list of pathnames for those commands.  Take the directory names of these and add them to `PATH` in the script itself (somewhere at the start of the script):

```
PATH=$PATH:/some/directory/path:/another/directory/path
```

Doing this in the script guarantees that the tool will be found by the script.

In the end, it may be that all you need is to add `/usr/sbin`:

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/sbin
```

The other alternative is to use the tools wih their absolute path, like using `/usr/sbin/arp` instead of just `arp`.

Answer (score 1):

To run `arp` script in `crontab`, it is necessary to use the `arp` path as `/sbin/arp` instead of `arp`, because `crontab` run scripts located in `/bin` by default, while `arp` is located in `/sbin/`.